# Count distinct pair of values grouped by other values

Tags: sql, ms-access

Access 2013 SQL.

I have 2 tables that I am joining over a shared "ID" field.

I want a Count of Distinct fld1+fld2 values Grouped By Book and Name.

How to do this in Access 2013 SQL please. I have nothing that doesn't produce a syntax error or other aggregate error after 2 hours of trying.

Example data:

```
Table1
ID, Name
1, "John"
2, "John"
3, "John"
1, "Tom"
3, "Tom"
3, "Jack"


Table2
ID, Book, Fld1, Fld2
1, "A", 1, 1
2, "A", 1, 2
2, "A", 1, 2
1, "B", 1, 1
2, "B", 1, 3
3, "B", 1, 3
```

The expected result set:

```
Book, Name, Count()
A, John, 2
A, Tom, 1
A, Jack, 0
B, John, 2
B, Tom, 2
B, Jack, 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You say, for instance, that you want to group by `id1` and `id2`.  Yet, you actually show data grouped by `fld1` and `fld2`.  And what is a count of unique combinations supposed to be.

Comment: It's unclear how the two tables are related. I suppose they share a common `id`? That would be extremely uncommon, but `id2`, the only other field in table1 seems not to be the link. Am I right to suspect `id` in the two tables to be it?

Comment: Your example data makes no sense.  No table has the two columns `fld1`, `fld2`.

Comment: My apologies. Hopefully the description and the example are clear now. Obviously my confusion stems from how to define the problem. I think it is correct and complete now.

Comment: No still the IDs make no sense. An ID usually uniquely identifies a record in the table. Your IDs do not. Again: How are the two tables related? On first (and second) glance they seem to have absolutely nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Very sorry for my inability to correctly define the problem. However, the solution from Thorsten below does exactly what I need. Tested and verified on my data. Thanks!

Comment: In answer to Thorsten, yes, I was trying to generically define my issue and ID2 and ID3 where not very good example field names. Should have been city and name.

Comment: I cleaned up the example. Hopefully more intuitive and correct now. But one caveat: Thorsten's solution below won't work with my new example. In the case where Jack has ZERO for "A", that won't get included in the result set. How do I get ZERO values included in the result set instead of ignored. Thanks! You guys are brilliant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the data distinct before aggregating:

```
select id2, id3, count(*)
from
(
  select distinct t1.id2, t2.id3, t2.fld1, t2.fld2
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
) t
group by t.id2, t.id3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a basic `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select t2.fld1, t2.fld2, count(*)
from t1 inner join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
group by t2.fld1, t2.fld2;
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "unique combinations".

Comment: Hi Gordon. I want to count the unique combinations of fld1 and fld2 in Table2. I will update to provide example data and expected result set. Sorry I forgot that.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. What should I do to give you credit for your help?

Comment: @user2184214 . . . You should upvote and accept answers that you feel are worthy.  You should *not* wantonly upvote answers -- they'll be rejected anyway by Stack Overflow.  The thank you is appreciated.  Cheers.